# Burninate [turboc++], or at least show a warning for new questions using it?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

Questions with the [turboc++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/turboc%2b%2b) tag usually seem to end up with downvotes or closure. As of this moment in time, the first page of questions with this tag has a net total of -24 votes (26 downvotes, 2 upvotes), one question on hold, and two closed. Part of this is probably due to the tag itself, since Turbo C++ is so old that it's not relevant to anyone trying to do modern programming.

Can we burninate/blacklist this tag, or at least add some sort of warning to new questions being created with this tag, something along the lines of

> Turbo C++ is extremely outdated, and modern code may not work in this compiler. Please consider using a different compiler, such as Code::Blocks or Microsoft Visual Studio.

I know we can edit the tag itself to add such a warning, but judging from the way other tags with warnings attached seem to be (ab)used, people tend to overlook such things. Perhaps we can do something a little more forceful here?

Comment: It's a legitimate and specific tag, so I don't think it should be removed.

Comment: A valid use for the tag would be if someone had to maintain legacy code.

Comment: I really hate it when people say "Why do you use this legacy tech". It was VC6 in my case. Because I already have a legacy project, anyone? Some universities in India are still using Turbo C in their courses, so there are people stuck in it.

Comment: There are still questions about it, so I guess that the language must be still in use. We should keep it.

Comment: If we burninated tags just because people ask a lot of bad questions in them, I think all the most popular ones would be the first to go...

Answer (score 26):

I disagree. It relates to programming. Why should be it removed then?

> the first page of questions with this tag has a net total of -24 votes (26 downvotes, 2 upvotes)

There also quite upvoted  [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/turboc%2b%2b?sort=votes&pageSize=50) tagged with it. This page has total score of 110 +.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree.

Going through the burnination criteria:

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**
   Yes, clearly. This is decidedly not a Meta tag; it's a legitimate topic that it's possible to be an expert on.
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**
   Yes, absolutely. This tag is about a tool used exclusively for programming and is therefore on-topic.
3. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**
   Again, yes because questions can actually be *about* that topic.
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**
   Yes - it refers to a specific compiler. What else could it refer to?