# Rename [turboc++] → [turbo-c++]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I would like to propose renaming the tag [turboc++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/turboc%2b%2b) to [turbo-c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/turbo-c%2b%2b).

Since it was decided that questions about the [Turbo C++ compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_C%2B%2B) are [on-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254827/3357935), I don't see any reason why the tag shouldn't reflect the program's proper name.

The new name would match the tag format for other legacy compilers. ([turbo-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/turbo-c), [turbo-pascal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/turbo-pascal), [borland-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/borland-c), [borland-c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/borland-c%2b%2b))

Comment: Tag renamed and a syn from turboc++ to turbo-c++ created.

Comment: @JonClements It appears that [tag:turbobasic] is also missing a space. Can it be renamed to [tag:turbo-basic], or should I make a separate request?

Comment: There's only 3 questions for that :)

Comment: @JonClements I don't have enough rep on SO to retag them myself.

Comment: Oh... Yeah that whole tag name the same except a hyphen restriction thing. Done.

Comment: @JonClements Thanks. Would you mind posting the rename as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: No real need. The question and status completed is sufficient here.

Comment: @JonClements did they fix the problem with Community bumping these questions?

Comment: No, still a problem.  Yesterday I hammered a question with *twenty* bumps out of its misery.  Well, ours.  https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1231235/timeline